# How to save and set headers on each request with Angular Interceptors

Tags: angularjs, header, session-cookies, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to setup token auth but can't seem to figure out a good way to save the headers the server is sending me into a cookie. I then need to read that value out of the cookie and into the new request headers.

I'm using Angular 1.5

Here's some simple code I've been trying to work with:

```
os.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

  return {
   'request': function(config) {

       var access_token = $cookies.get('access-token');
       var token_type = $cookies.get('token-type');
       var client = $cookies.get('client');
       var uid = $cookies.get('uid');

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['access-token'] = access_token;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['token-type'] = token_type;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['client'] = client;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['uid'] = uid;

    },

    'response': function(response) {

       $cookies.put('access-token', 'oatmeal');
       $cookies.put('token-type', 'oatmeal');
       $cookies.put('client', 'oatmeal');
       $cookies.put('uid', 'oatmeal');

    }
  };

}]);
```

EDIT: People have been commenting trying to show me how to set headers. I can do that easily, as you can see in the example. What I need to do is save the response headers after I've made a request. These need to be saved into a cookie which is what my question pertains to.

I'm interested in a method that doesn't require me to run some function in the .then part of every single API request I do, that's not DRY and seems like madness...

Comment: This article should help http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Comment: No need to store in cookie. Get the token from response headers on the login authorization and store in sessionStorage then use interceptors to update request headers. You don't use `defaults` for that , update the actual config object. See examples in article

Comment: But if I don't store it in cookies it will be lost when they reload the page..?

Comment: that's where sessionStorage comes in.

Comment: are you still needing help with this?